# Extending Union Types Alias in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, alias

I'm trying to limit some string fields to be only of certain values at compile time. The problem is that those values should be extendable.
Here's a simplified example:

```
type Foobar = 'FOO' | 'BAR';

interface SomeInterface<T extends Foobar> {
  amember: T;

  [key: string]: string; // this really has to stay
}

// let's test it

const yes = {
    amember: 'FOO'
} as SomeInterface<'FOO'>; // compiles as expected

//    const no = {
//        amember: 'BAZ'
//    } as SomeInterface<'BAZ'>; // Type '"BAZ"' does not satisfy the constraint 'Foobar' as expected

// so far so good
// Now the problem

abstract class SomeClass<T extends Foobar> {
  private anotherMember: SomeInterface<T>;
}

type Foobarbaz = Foobar | 'BAZ';

class FinalClass extends SomeClass<Foobarbaz> { //no good anymore
}
```

The error is

> Type 'Foobarbaz' does not satisfy the constraint 'Foobar'.   Type
>   '"BAZ"' is not assignable to type 'Foobar'.

So the question is: how in typescript can I limit a 'type' to be of certain strings only, but have it extendable with other strings?
Or is this an XY problem and there's an obvious better solution?

Typescript 2.3.4 but i think i can upgrade to 2.4 if there's magic there.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think you're using the word "extendable" in a different sense from what the keyword `extends` means.  By saying the type is "extendable" you're saying you'd like to be able to *widen* the type to accept *more* values.  But when something `extends` a type, it means that you are *narrowing* the type to accept *fewer* values.

`SomeInterface<T extends Foobar>` can essentially be only one of the following four types:

- `SomeInterface<'FOO'|'BAR'>`: `amember` can be either `'FOO'` or `'BAR'`
- `SomeInterface<'FOO'>`: `amember` can be only `'FOO'`
- `SomeInterface<'BAR'>`: `amember` can be only `'BAR'`
- `SomeInterface<never>`: `amember` cannot take any value

I kind of doubt that's actually what you want, but only you know that for sure.

---

On the other hand, if you want `SomeInterface<T>` to be defined such that `T` can *always* be either `FOO` or `BAR`, but also possibly some other `string` values, you want something that TypeScript doesn't exactly provide, which would be specifying a lower bound for `T`.  Something like `SomeInterface<T`[`super`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6613#issuecomment-175314703)`Foobar extends string>`, which isn't valid TypeScript.

But you probably only care about the type of *`amember`*, and not `T`. If you want `amember` to be either `FOO` or `BAR`, but also possibly some other `string` values, you could specify it like this:

```
interface SomeInterface<T extends string = never> {
  amember: Foobar | T;
  [key: string]: string; 
}
```

where `T` is just the union of extra literals you'd like to allow.  If you don't want to allow any extra, use `never`, or just leave out the type parameter (since I've put `never` as the default).

Let's see it in action:

```
const yes = {
    amember: 'FOO'
} as SomeInterface; // good, 'FOO' is a Foobar

const no = {
    amember: 'BAZ'
} as SomeInterface; // bad, 'BAZ' is not a Foobar

abstract class SomeClass<T extends string> {
  private anotherMember: SomeInterface<T>;
}

class FinalClass extends SomeClass<'BAZ'> { 
} // fine, we've added 'BAZ'

// let's make sure we did:
type JustChecking = FinalClass['anotherMember']['amember']
// JustChecking === 'BAZ' | 'FOO' | 'BAR'
```

---

Did I answer your question?  Hope that helps.

Comment: yes, that seems to cut it. The only puristic concern is that `amember: Foobar | T;` reads like T can be anything and not necessary Foobar's descendant. But that's a minor. I guess you're right about missing `super`.

Answer (score 16):

To achieve what you need, you can use [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) via the `&` symbol.

```
type Foobar = 'FOO' | 'BAR';
type FoobarBaz = Foobar | 'BAZ'; // or: 'BAZ' | Foobar
```

[image: Example of intersected type]

Comment: Prettier strips off that extra `&`. Can you link the source for this trick?

Comment: @jayarjo there is a link to (now deprecated) documentation for intersection types. I can't find any up to date documentation for it though.

Comment: The '&' symbol is actually unnecessary. Stripping it will result in the same type.

Answer (score 2):

> how in typescript can I limit a 'type' to be of certain strings only, but have it extendable with other strings?

No idea what you X problem is, but you always can introduce another generic parameter, and limit a type by declaring that it extends that parameter. Typescript 2.3 [supports default types for generic parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults), so with `Foobar` as default you can use `SomeInterface` with one argument as before, and when you need it to extend something else you provide that explicitly:

```
type Foobar = 'FOO' | 'BAR';

interface SomeInterface<T extends X, X extends string=Foobar> {
  amember: T;

  [key: string]: string; // this really has to stay
}

// let's test it

const yes = {
    amember: 'FOO'
} as SomeInterface<'FOO'>; // compiles as expected


abstract class SomeClass<T extends X, X extends string=Foobar> {
  private anotherMember: SomeInterface<T, X>;
}

type Foobarbaz = Foobar | 'BAZ';

class FinalClass extends SomeClass<Foobarbaz, Foobarbaz> { 
}
```

**UPDATE**

I think I understand the problem now. One solution is to encode union types like Foobar as `keyof` of some artificial interface type used to represent keys only (value types are not used and do not matter). That way, by extending the interface you sort of "naturally" extend the set of keys:

```
interface FoobarKeys { FOO: { }; BAR: { } };

type Foobar = keyof FoobarKeys;

interface SomeInterface<X extends FoobarKeys = FoobarKeys> {
  amember: keyof X;

  [key: string]: string; // this really has to stay
}



abstract class SomeClass<X extends FoobarKeys = FoobarKeys> {
    protected anotherMember: SomeInterface<X> = {
        amember: 'FOO'
    };

    protected amethod(): void { 
        this.bmethod(this.anotherMember); // no error
    }

    protected bmethod(aparam: SomeInterface<X>): void { 

    }
}

// let's extend it

interface FoobarbazKeys extends FoobarKeys { BAZ: {} };
type Foobarbaz = keyof FoobarbazKeys;

class FinalClass extends SomeClass<FoobarbazKeys> {
    private f() {
        this.bmethod({amember: 'BAZ'})
    } 
}
```

Comment: The X in the question is this: the base class should be able to operate only on anything Foobar while children might have additional values. Here's extended:

Comment: Formatting in comments is hard,
 thus link [gist](https://gist.github.com/dooreelko/85467af712a312002a79e2e171cbcbed)

Comment: Eventually I went @jcalz way, that's why I marked it as correct. Yours is also correct and extra kudos for the `keyof` operator.