# how can I express that a parameter can extend a list of strings in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a method that takes a `string` parameter. However, I want to constrain that parameter a little bit. So, I create a *union type* with the strings I want to accept:

```
type Foo = 'a' | 'b';
```

now, I have a simple method:

```
function bar(foo: Foo) {
    // do something with that string
}
```

What I want to do is allow a caller to pass other strings (besides `a` and `b`). However, I want them to sort of *extend* the original union type.

```
function bar<T extends Foo>(str: T) {
    // do something with that string
}
type Bar = Foo | 'c';
// this doesn't work: Argument of type 'Bar' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Foo'. Type '"c"' is not assignable to type 'Foo'.
bar('c' as Bar);
```

Is there any way to express this constraint in TypeScript?

Comment: If you can pass in any string how is it different from string?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir in the OP he said "other", not "any". He wants to extend the set of allowed strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending union type alias in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745441/extending-union-type-alias-in-typescript)

Answer (score 2):

@jscalz 's comment made me reconsider my answer.

From a classical OOP perspective, the `extends` constraint in `bar<T extends Foo>(arg: T)` on the generic parameter would mean that `T` possesses all properties of `Foo` *and* more. So with this constraint you can safely assume in your `bar` that `arg` behaves at least like `Foo` (and has the same property structure).

However, in your case, `T` is neither a `class` or an `interface` but a **union of string literals** and this is where the `extends` gets pointless:

Let's assume `bar<T extends Foo>(arg: T)` worked as you want it to (as stated in your OP), meaning, `T` is a superset of string literals on top of `Foo`. This would mean that in your `bar()` function you would have no control at all over which values `arg` holds – it may hold *any* kind of values and you might as well use *any*.

Given the above, your only chance to control what makes it's way into `bar()` is to use `function bar(args: Bar)`, where `Bar = Foo | 'c'` which then also allows you to call `bar('c');` without casting.

---

**Original answer:**

---

Defining `type Bar` as [intersection type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.5) seems to at least tame the typescript linting errors: `type Bar = Foo & 'c';`.

Below I list the relevant parts (at least to my understanding) from the typescript spec that define that an intersection of types actually leads to a "Subtype-Supertype" relationship which is recognized by the `extends` constraint:

In [3.11.3 Subtypes and Supertypes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3113-subtypes-and-supertypes) it says:

> S is a subtype of a type T, and T is a supertype of S, if S has no excess properties with respect to T (3.11.5) and one of the following is true:
>
> [...]
>
> - S is a union type and each constituent type of S is a subtype of T.

Moreover in [3.11.4 Assignment Compatibility](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3114-assignment-compatibility) (made bold by me):

> S is **assignable** to a type T, and T is assignable from S, if S has no excess properties with respect to T (3.11.5) and one of the following is true:
>
> [...]
>
> - S is a union type and each constituent type of S is assignable to T.

With regards to the `extends` keyword, the Typescript handbook states the following (made bold by me):

> For practical purposes, type compatibility is dictated by assignment compatibility, **even in the cases of the implements and extends clauses.**

In your case `Foo` equates to `S` in the spec and `Bar` is your supertype (or superset) which equates to `T` spec.

**However,** I am not sure if this answer satisfies you because you can also write `bar('x' as Bar);` and the compiler won't show an error despite 'x' not being included in your types.

I think your best shot is to simply use `function bar(x: Bar)`. Which then also allows you to call `bar('c');`

Comment: `Foo & 'c'` is equivalent to `never` (no string can be *both* `"c"` and *also* either `"a"` or `"b"`).  It's unlikely that is the intent here.  More likely, the question is using `extends` incorrectly;  instead of `T extends Foo`, the intent is more like `T super Foo`, but that [doesn't exist in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7265).