# How to ensure a TypeScript argument is a union with a specific type

Tags: typescript, generics, union

How can I write a TypeScript function which ensures that an argument is a union that happens to include another (more specific) union? For example:

```
type Command = { 
  name: string 
  [key: string]: any
}

type Insert = { name: 'insert'; text: string }
type Delete = { name: 'delete'; position: number }
type CoreCommand = Insert | Delete

type Replace = { name: 'replace'; position: number; text: string }
type CustomCommand = CoreCommand | Replace

const exec = <T ???>(command: T) => {
  switch (command.name) {
    case 'insert':
      // ...
      break
    case 'delete':
      // ...
      break
    // ...
  }
}
```

In the above code, how can I ensure that the `T` generic type is guaranteed to include the `CoreCommand` union type, while still letting it satisfy other "custom" commands too?

Can you also ensure that the custom commands don't conflict with the core commands?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending union type alias in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745441/extending-union-type-alias-in-typescript)

Comment: TypeScript doesn't have lower-bounded generics, so you can't do that this way,   Instead why not something like `<T>(command: T | CoreCommand) => ...`?

Comment: Hey @jcalz, it does look similar to that one. The issue with the `T | CoreCommand` I think is that since I can't guarantee `T` and `CoreCommand` don't clash, then if I use a `switch` in exec, I can't guarantee that `command.name === 'insert_text'` means that I'm working with the core `Insert` command anymore.

Comment: I guess the real question is how to extend a *discriminated* union and keep the discrimination in effect? While allowing a "core" function to accept any potential extensions, without caring about the extended bits?

Comment: `Exclude<T, { name: CoreCommand['name'] }> | CoreCommand` then?

Comment: like [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgtgEygXigbwFBW1AdgQzggC4oBnYAJwEtcBzLHAbQGsIRSKb6BdU-XCAwBfDKEhQAkrjIp0eQiSgByWmWUBuKMAAewTlVp0oo8dAAiEADZy0CoqWUJrmqGAD2ZUrgCucAEYQlCZi4NAw7pQQ8Eio0rIAPlCWVhgAZj64AMbA1O64UNRkEVExABQ6-IIAlKQ6hbIl0YjojNhRwD6UBRUAdAREKMioAERqI1AAZJPaYe5pUDq9usBDo1xGI9VQCUl9A9DDo85WE9OzkPOLvR6yR1AjvgFBWxoiGFn5FFAQOhBZcgAPAAVH56CC4BCNRAAPjKnzgcAECFIAFEdFkrD5nCCADTyA6kJoxJjKA7KHgmGE7WCRZoIbbIamYHCFBZlACERWJiHh7kRyOq2w6XVwb1ZZAA7tRgFkABZQPkCyH9RTbFmsnBZfBkaCqGTKYhtTWshFIlUrcUmzX+KL4FjG006vUnQ2O61m5E3TxW604W0Qe3G0SiX7-Mp2QkqNTKfFUfQPfATYTVIA)?

Comment: Thank you @jcalz! I think using the abstract command interface paired with type guard assertions might be the best way to do it. I'll go with that then. If you want to write it up in an answer I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that your `CustomCommand` already includes `CoreCommand` as expression `CoreCommand | Replace` equals `Insert | Delete | Replace`. I really don't see even any polymorphic need in your case, just use `CustomCommand`:

```
const exec = (command: CustomCommand) => {
  switch (command.name) { // command.name is properly insert | delete | replace
    case 'insert':
      // ...
      break
    case 'delete':
      // ...
      break
    // ...
  }
```

For other thing, how we can ensure that you create new commands matching the interface of the `Command`. We can do so by conditional type which will check if the name is not already in `CoreCommands`:

```
type CreateCommand<T extends Command> = T['name'] extends CoreCommand['name'] ? never : T; 
type Insert2 = CreateCommand<{ name: 'insert'; position: number; text: string }>

type CustomCommand = CoreCommand | Insert2 // it will evaluate to Insert | Delete only
```

`CreateCommand` will evaluate to never if we will pass type with `name` property already existing in core commands. So types which will use the same name field will be skipped during doing the union.

Also you can create additional utility type for creating union which always includes CoreCommands:

```
type Replace = CreateCommand<{ name: 'replace'; position: number; text: string }>
type Change = CreateCommand<{ name: 'change'; position: number; text: string }>

type MakeCommands<NewCommand extends Command> = CoreCommand | NewCommand
type CustomCommand = MakeCommands<Replace | Change>; // hre we always add CoreCommand to the list of commands
```

The last but not least is how to make polymorphic the exec function:

```
const exec = <C extends Command>(command: C, f: (x: C) => void) => f(command);

const comm = { name: 'replace', position: 1, text: 'text' };
// below `as` is only used to block direct inference by TS from the const
// it is not needed for real code
const result = exec(comm as CustomCommand, (incommand) => {
  switch (incommand.name) { // icommand is here CustomCommand
    case 'insert':
      // ...
      break
    case 'delete':
      // ...
      break
    // ...
  }
});
```

Above `exec` will infer type from first argument, and already infered type will pass to the function being second argument. Thanks to that we will have specified type which will be having CoreCommands, but also any command included in the type passed as `command` argument.

Comment: Thank you! The issue is that `exec` is defined in "core", and the custom commands are defined elsewhere. So when `exec` is defined there are no custom commands yet. But I'd like it to be able to accept custom commands *as well as* the core commands, for whatever extensions another developer wants to make.

Comment: Exactly the last snippet allows on that. It ifers by first argument and the only requirement is that there is Core command included. Function which is passed can be passed in different scope.