# Extend an interface which has a property that is a set of values

Tags: typescript

I have this interface:

```js
type Abc = "a" | "b" | "c"

interface Foobar_1_0 {
  fooBar: Abc;
  otherProp: number;
}

interface Foobar_1_1 extends Foobar_1_0 {
  fooBar: Abc | "d" | "e" | "f"
}
```

My desire is to have `Foobar_1_1`'s foo property to be one of a, b, c, d, e, f, and to have the inherited `otherProp` via extension. However, it is not working, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you check again, for me it looks it is exactly what you want,

Comment: This looks ok. Can you post the code where you get the error?

Comment: Please consider providing a [mcve] as described in [ask].  Right now [I cannot reproduce the issue](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggRgYygXigIgIZqgH3XbPNBNAWACgKBLAO2AgCcAzDBaAMQHtO4MGB9AIz8ADFADeFKFCbcAQnwBcsRBQC+FanUYs2ULjz5ChEqTPlKVSIgBNC6CPbRMy5DZXIJONAM7AZyga8AsKCKKbk0rKcCgzKaI7qFF6+-gDmgdzBxmKo4uYxlmgEUGoA3MneflAAFpmGISaoALIYwDUAdAwYNDacALYAFACUUAA8UCIdAKxQAPxQaVDKTEA).  Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question to correctly show how it's going wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extending union type alias in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745441/extending-union-type-alias-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is that `Foobar_1_1` is not a subset of `Foobar_1_0` because property `fooBar` in the `Foobar_1_1` is wider type then the original type has. With union types subset is something which has the same amount or less variants. So for example `a | b` is subset of `a | b | c`, but in your case it is another way round. Consider the proof:

```
type ExtendsAbc = Abc | "d" | "e" | "f" extends Abc ? true : false 
// false it doesn't extend
```

Above clearly says your type is not extending the original one, and that is why the error happens.

In order to have all properties extended, but make property `fooBar` wider type we can omit this property during extending by `Omit` utility type, consider:

```
interface Foobar_1_1 extends Omit<Foobar_1_0, 'fooBar'> {
  fooBar: Abc | "d" | "e" | "f"
}
```

Now the interface works and `fooBar` property is able to not extend the `fooBar` from `Foobar_1_0`.